# Raspberry Pi Zero g_mass_storage module unrecognized

Tags: partitioning, raspberry-pi, usb-storage

I was gifted an Aluratek digital photo frame (Model #ADPFD10F). Nice frame except for having to sneakernet picture updates.

Though I had never used the `g_mass_storage module` on the pi zero I had read a little about it and found a couple of fairly straightforward tutorials. I followed this tutorial over at [MagPi](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive).

Everything seemed great. I was able to connect the pi to the usb port on my tv, update the shared folder from my laptop, and watch the folder refresh with more photos on my tv. The same goes for when I plugged the pi into my laptop.

After a brief moment I was alerted that I had plugged in an external drive. This was not the case, however, for the photoframe. The frame would recognize that a usb device was plugged in but stated there was "No File Found".

I emailed back and forth with Aluratek's tech support but they were unable to help.

After some experimentation I did find that the photoframe will only display images from the first partition of a drive. i.e. I formatted a regular sandisk usb drive into two partitions and only pictures from the first partition were displayed.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Still fairly new to some of these concepts so if any additional information is needed from me I am happy to provide to the best of my abilities.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is, can you clarify what you need. btw, even Windows doesn't like more than one partition on a USB stick/SD

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I'm in a bit over my head at this point I think. I'm confused as to why my laptop and television would be able to see the drive and the files it contains and the photo frame would be able to see the drive but not any files (which makes me think the partition experimentation is a red herring). I'm just looking for some path forward if it is possible it all.

Comment: What type of SD Card are you using? Some devices won't read SDHC or SDXC versions.

Comment: I used sandisk SDXC microSDs for this. When I formatted the SD and just put pictures on it the frame seemed to work fine. I eventually gave up hope and just built a frame from scratch. Thanks for all help here!